# Gnome-Terminal and Emacs randomly flicker (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, flicker

I've searched existing questions here, but nothing quite matches (and the closest match's solution was not relevant to my system).

Since upgrading my desktop to 18.04 about 6 weeks ago, I've noticed a random-but-brief flickering that occurs in my terminal and emacs windows. No other apps (that I've noticed, at least). And it is rarely (if ever) the entire window; usually about 30-40% of the window will flicker. The flicker lasts less than a second before stopping. I haven't seen it happen in any window that has the focus, either.

The closest answer I found blamed a display refresh-rate of over 60, but my `monitors.xml` file has the refresh rate set at 60, and the settings panel shows it as actually being 59.95. So I don't think that's the problem here.

The video card is a GTX1080 from NVIDIA, using their drivers.

Any ideas?